# Value of type 'T' has no dynamic member 'object' using key path from root type 'T'

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I had a class like this:

```
class ObjectA:ObservableObject { 
  @Published var type:ObjectSheetType = .none
}
```

and I was using a class like this to process instances of this kind of object:

```
class ProcessObject {

  @ObservedObject private var object:ObjectA

  init(object:ObjectA) {
    self.object = object
  }

  process() {
    if object.type == .big {
     // bla bla
    }
    ...
  }
```

Then I have decided to add another class:

```
class ObjectB:ObservableObject { 
  @Published var type:ObjectSheetType = .none
}
```

and a protocol

```
protocol ObjectProtocol {
  var type:ObjectSheetType { get set }
}
```

This protocol was added to both classes: `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`.

Then the class `ProcessObject` was modified to accept objects of both kinds:

```
class processObject<T:ObjectProtocol, ObservableObject > {

  @ObservedObject private var object:T

  init(object:T) {
    self.object = object
  }
```

> Error: Referencing subscript 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' requires wrapper 'ObservedObject.Wrapper'
> Insert '$'
> Value of type 'T' has no dynamic member 'object' using key path from root type 'T'

error pointing to

```
if object.type == .big {
```

but also Xcode wants me to use $ in front of every published properties of `object`?

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59504489/12299030? BTW @ObservedObject  has no sense inside class, it is valid only inside SwiftUI view.

Comment: May be helpful for somebody, as of xcode14.1, this error is also returned if there is a typo in the  variable name. In the example above  `if object.types == .big {` returns this extremely confusing error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is to fix the protocol conformance of T because now ObservableObject is seen as another generic type and not the protocol.

Use & to say that T should conform to both protocols

```
class ProcessObject<T: ObjectProtocol & ObservableObject> {

}
```

Another way is to say that ObjectProtocol inherits from ObservableObject and then only use ObjectProtocol in all the conform declarations

```
protocol ObjectProtocol: ObservableObject {
    var type:ObjectSheetType { get set }
}
```

but that changes what ObjectProtocol is and you may not want that tight coupling between the two protocols

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain your last phrase: `but that changes what ObjectProtocol is and you may not want that tight coupling between the two protocols` ?

Comment: I always thought the comma on the <> was saying both.