# how to protocol a publisher for SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am refactoring / adding features to some code and encountered a situation where I want to migrate by protocoling the types.

Currently I have a data type like this:

```
struct Result {
  let a: Int
  let b: Int
  let c: Int
}
```

and an `ObservableObject` like this:

```
class Worker1 : ObservableObject {
   @Published var results: [Result] // this data is rendered by the UI against the concrete type of "Result"
}
```

and some views similar to this (using the `Result` type):

```
struct SomeUIComponent: View {
  @Binding var results: [Result]
  ....
}
```

I am in the process of migrating to an augmented result type (identical otherwise to the original result)

```
struct Result2 {
  let a: Int
  let b: Int
  let c: Int
  let d: Int // this along with some additional non-trivial things are new
}
```

handled by a new `Worker2` ObservableObject

```
class Worker2: ObservableObject {
  @Published var results: [Result2] // I want this as a protocol instead
}
```

for the older UI components, they only utilize the common fields `a` and `b`

while some new components care about the newly added fields.

I want to back patch the existing UI components gradually by working against the protocol types rather than the concrete types directly

To achieve this I created a set of protocols to align with the original `Result` type and implemented it on both the original `Result` as well as the newly defined `Result2`:

```
// currently aligned with the original Result type
protocol ResultProtocol {
  var a: Int {get}
  var b: Int {get}
  var c: Int {get}
}
```

I need an additional protocol to support `Worker1` publishers and the new `Worker2` publishing of the `ResultProtocol`  type (rather than the concrete type it had been defined to use earlier). This is important to allow gradual replacement of parts without fixing a large combination of things.

I tried this:

```
// create a supporting protocol which the UI components can access , reading the protocol stubbed type rather than the concrete type
protocol WorkerProtocol {
  var resultsPublisher:  Published<[ResultProtocol]>.Publisher {get}
}
```

and now hitting a wall when trying to extend the "Worker1" implementation to handle this:

```
extension Worker1 : WorkerProtocol {
  var resultsPublisher:  Published<[ResultProtocol]>.Publisher { $results } // this doesn't work, it doesn't "cast" the concrete type "Result" to the protocol type 
// I believe the concrete type is Published<[Result]>.Publisher, while Result does implement the ResultProtocol, this doesn't compile
// Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
}
```

I tried to cast it / map it / erase to anytype it / etc.

example:

```
$results as  Published<[ResultsProtocol]>.Publisher
$results.eraseToAny
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59504489/12299030?