# @Published not updating UI on changing value of viewmodel

Tags: swiftui, property-wrapper-published

In my ViewController (`UIHostingController`) i have viewModel (reference type) shared between ViewController and its rootView. And viewModel has one property which is wrapped as `@Published`.

1. On receving response to viewcontroller from api call.
2. updating viewModel with received data from server
3. here after setting value to `@Published` it is not updating the UI

ViewController Code:

```
final class DashboardSceneViewController: UIHostingController<DashboardSceneView> {
    var viewModel: DashboardSceneViewModel?
    func setVm(response : Model){
        viewModel.data = response. ///Here it should update DashboardSceneView But not updating
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
protocol DashboardSceneViewModel   {
    var delegate: DashboardSceneViewDelegate? { get set }
    var homeJson : HomeModel? {get set}
}


class DefaultDashboardSceneViewModel: DashboardSceneViewModel{
    @Published var homeJson: Model?
}
```

View:

```
//Not getting redrawn on change in @published property change
struct DashboardSceneView: View {
    var viewModel: DashboardSceneViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if viewModel.homeJson != nil {
                Text(viewModel.homeJson?.header ?? "")
            }
            Button("Tap"){
                print()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we don't use view model objects in SwiftUI, you have to learn `@State` and `@Binding`. For api call use `.task { state = await download() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Published does not update SwiftUI view by itself.

Your view model should be

1. is-a `ObservableObject`, and
2. view model property wrapped into `@ObservedObject` in view

See this one for similar scenario with observable protocol https://stackoverflow.com/a/59504489/12299030

Answer (score 1):

In order for `@Published` to update the UI, it's parent(`DefaultDashboardSceneViewModel`) should be conform to `ObservableObject`:

```
protocol DashboardSceneViewModel: ObservableObject {
```

Now, for `ObservableObject` to bind to your `View`, you need to mark it with `@StateObject`. However, since `DashboardSceneView` did not initialize `viewModel` you mark it with `@ObservedObject`:

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel: DashboardSceneViewModel
```