# swiftui Generic parameter could not be inferred

Tags: generics, swiftui

I get compiler error:

> Generic parameter 'ViewModel' could not be inferred

at this point

```
NavigationLink(destination: TabbedView(viewModel: getModel(subSection: subSection.subSection), contentController: ContentController(), subSection: subSection.subSection)) {
                        Text(subSection.subSection.title)
                    }
```

**my functions:**

```
func getModel<ViewModel: ModelProtocol>(subSection: SubSection) -> ViewModel {
    if(SubSection.TEXT.contains(subSection.category)){
        return getLiteratureModel(subSection: subSection) as! ViewModel
    }
    if(SubSection.QUESTION.contains(subSection.category)){
        return getTwoStepsModel(subSection: subSection) as! ViewModel
    }
}
func getLiteratureModel(subSection: SubSection) -> some ModelProtocol{
    let literatureModel = LiteratureModel<Any>()
    
    literatureModel.update(subSectionId: subSection.id, category: subSection.category, lightMode: colorScheme == .light, dataSource: dataSource)
    literatureModel.prepareData()
    
    return literatureModel
}
func getTwoStepsModel(subSection: SubSection) -> some ModelProtocol{
    let twoStepsModel = TwoStepsModel<Any>()
 
    twoStepsModel.update(subSectionId: subSection.id, category: subSection.category, lightMode: colorScheme == .light, dataSource: dataSource)
    twoStepsModel.prepareData()
  
    return twoStepsModel
}
```

**my classes**

```
class LiteratureModel<ViewModel>: TextViewModel, ModelProtocol {...}

class TwoStepsModel<ViewModel>: TextViewModel, ModelProtocol {...}
```

of **Protocol**:

```
protocol ModelProtocol: ObservableObject {
associatedtype ViewModel
var htmlText: String { get } ...}
```

**View** that is called:

```
struct TabbedView<ViewModel>: View where ViewModel: ModelProtocol{
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
var contentController: ContentController
var subSection: SubSection

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geoProxy in
        TabView {
            if(SubSection.TEXT.contains(subSection.category)){
                BaseTextView(viewModel: viewModel as! LiteratureModel<ViewModel>, contentController: contentController).padding()
                    .tabItem {
                        Text(NSLocalizedString("lesson", comment: ""))
                    } }
            if(SubSection.QUESTION.contains(subSection.category)){
                BaseTextView(viewModel: viewModel as! TwoStepsModel<ViewModel>, contentController: contentController).padding()
                    .tabItem {
                        Text(NSLocalizedString("lesson", comment: ""))
                    } }
                    ...
```

My intention is, to reuse **BaseTextView** and therefore using generic type for the two Observables **LiteratureModel** and **TwoStepsModel**. I have to instantiate these classes before **TabbedView** gets instantiated, otherwise the Observables would be unwillingly reinstantiated.

Maybe I'm confused about **Protocol**, **Generics**, **Typealias**, **Opaque** ...

Comment: This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59504489/12299030.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but in contrast to this sample I have two different Implementations of that one Protocol.